# ActiveRecord is showing wrong column defaults

Tags: ruby, database, activerecord, sqlite, column-defaults

This is my first time using ActiveRecord in a non-rails application, and I'm running into a problem. ActiveRecord is able to figure out the columns I have in my sqlite3 database, but it can't figure out the default column values for some reason.

Here is the sql description for the table in question.

```
-- Describe ACCOUNTS
CREATE TABLE "accounts" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    "username" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "password_hash" BLOB NOT NULL,
    "creation_time" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT(strftime('%s', 'now')),
    "expiration_time" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT(strftime('%s', 'now') + 2592000)
)
```

I used the following code for loading my database file.

```
require 'active_record'
require './config.rb'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'sqlite3',
  :database => DB_FILE
)

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I look at the column defaults for the Account table with a REPL, this is what I get:

```
[10] pry(main)> Account.column_defaults
=> {"id"=>0,
 "username"=>nil,
 "password_hash"=>nil,
 "creation_time"=>0,
 "expiration_time"=>0}
```

I worked with ActiveRecord for a rails app before and it was smart enough to figure out the default values. For some reason, it can't figure them out now.

Am I doing something wrong here? I read that I can manually specify the default value with `default :id => bla`, but shouldn't ActiveRecord be able to figure out the defaults?

---

**Update:** I think I figured out a workaround. The hash returned by `Account.column_defaults` is writeable, and changing those elements seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :default_values

  private
    def default_values
      self.username ||= "default value"
      #etc...
    end
end
```

Comment: Since the `id` column is `autoincrement`, is there any way to get the next id that the database would use? Normally, it would keep incrementing the id, so if the last item had an id of 12 and you deleted it, the next item's id would be 13.

Comment: No, that value gets returned to ActiveRecord after it is inserted into the DB.